# How to initialise an int java array of size n initially empty?

Tags: java, arrays

In a function,I want to initialise a java array of max size n, which is empty initially.If I add 3 elements(say n>3) and return the array, the array should contain only the 3 elements and not 3 elements followed by (n-3) 0's.

```
    //PSEUDO CODE
        func(){
        //Create array A of max size 5
        A[0]=1;
        A[1]=2;
        A[2]=3;

        return A;
        }
        main(){
        int[] B=func();
        //B.length should give 3
        for (int i=0;i<B.length;i++){
          print B[i];
        }
        /*Should print 1 2 3
         and Not 1 2 3 0 0 
        */
       }
```

And I don't want to use array list.I want to use java array only.

Comment: This code is not valid Java.

Comment: I meant Pseudo code

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking. If you want an array containing 3 ints, what's wrong with `new int[] { 1, 2, 3}`?

Comment: We don't want pseudocode on this site.  We want actual code that shows an actual problem that I can actually copy, paste and reproduce.

Comment: @MahithBhima.: In stack overflow if any of the answer provided to your question seems useful to you and helps you - select that answer (green tick).

Comment: ok,dont know about it.Will do it from now on.

Comment: @Joe C I wanted answer only as a concept, and a one line of code which shows syntax for creation of the array.In that case I don't have to keep the entire code right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you only want to print the non-default values of the array. If your values are always different from zero, then you can just do:

```
for (int i=0;i<B.length;i++){
      if (B[i] != 0){
          print(B[i]);
      }
}
```

However, if your values can also be zero, you can also keep a counter of how many values you currently have, and only print that many values:

```
int counter = 3; //the array might be {1, 2, 3, 0, 0}
for (int i=0; i<counter; i++){
      print(B[i]); //will print "1 2 3"
}
```

The counter must be incremented everytime you add a value.
Both solutions are limited though, depending on how you access and use the array.

Comment: @jccint what if the value present in array is  {1,2,0,3}. Its not necessary that 0 will come in end of the array

Comment: @smrutiranjan That's one of the many limitations that the solution has. OP should probably explain his use case in more detail if something like that is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

then u have to make the array dynamic by urself. Everytime u add an element to the array create a new array of size=no of elements (let u r adding the 3rd element then size of new array would be 3). take the elements from old array to the new one. Each time u add 1 element u have to follow this.

Comment: Does that mean there no possible way to do it with a single array?

Comment: @MahithBhima if u already know number of elements that needs to be stored then u can predefine the size along with array declaration

Comment: Actually I am doing a filter function.So I don't know the number of elements to be stored.But I can keep a counter and do as suggested in the below comment.